# Visual Studio 2008 crashes when startup with Qt Add-in 1.1.4

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, crash, 64-bit, add-in

I use Windows 7 x64, Qt Add-in 1.1.4, Visual Studio 2008 Team Edition.
Does not work on multiple computers ... reinstalling Windows, Qt Add-in or VS2008 does not help(

The error report says that an error in msenv.dll

Please tell us how to fix it.
If possible, of course.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried to install Win7+Qt_Addin+MSVS2008 on i386 arch? You may also post you error report to Microsoft and Nokia support, in case if you have legal copied on apps...

Comment: I ran a test on Core i5, Quad Q6600 and Core 2 Duo

Comment: Just now install Qt Add-in 1.1.4 on my Win7 (x32) and it works fine with studio... When I'm asking you about arch, I mean OS arch, not the processors...

Comment: @mosg Thank you!

I know what went wrong... I have installed, not all features Visual Studio.
Everything worked when I installed all the components of the VS2008!!!

Comment: Please create an answer for this question with the solution mentioned in the comments and mark it as solved.

Comment: Got the same crash with Qt Add-in 1.2.5. The solution is (as @Lestat said) to install **all** components of Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: the original question got resolved by installing all features of VS2008;

---

However if your Visual Studio 2008 crashes (especially at startup) just like mine, even without Qt or any other Add-ins: open up `eventvwr.exe` and look for an Error with the exception code 5 (access violation on write) at offset `0x0000bdb8` in `msenv.dll`.

[image: vs2008_msenv_dll_crash_offset_0x0000bdb8]

**That** is a known bug for which there is [officially](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/525202/vs2008-faulting-application-name-devenv-exe) no workaround other than upgrade to VS2010.

In my experience sometimes it won't happen for a long time, sometimes you will need 2-4 attempts to start up an empty VS2008, and sometimes (in another environment, e.g. OS Windows Server 2008) no amount of retrying and rebooting is going to help.

If you work in a controlled environment, constrained to particular versions of Windows and Visual Studio, try to reduce how often you need to start VS2008 version of `DEVENV.EXE`. There are mitigation scenarios:

- Use another IDE, such as CLion (commercial product) or just Notepad++ / WinDbg
- Use IncrediBuild (commercial product, but FreeDev licenses are available): in command-line mode, it bypasses the GUI-laden DEVENV.EXE
- Use MSBuild or any other invoker of the Microsoft compilers that can bypass DEVENV.EXE
- Use fewer but larger VS solutions with more projects, rather than lots of 1-project solutions.

---

Finally, just in case the Social MSDN link stops working, here is a screenshot:

[image: social.msdn]